# Purpose to use timestamp datatype in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

1. What is the purpose to use timestamp datatype in sql server?
2. Do you have a concrete example of using timestamp in real business case?
3. When is it relevant to use timestampe datatype?

Thank you!

Comment: And just to spell out out: the timestamp type (with the not-correctly implemented alias name rowversion) has nothing to do with date and time. It is unfortunately convertible to datetime, but you basically get a garbage value. In the SQL standard, however, timestamp *does* mean date and time, so in this aspect SQL Server do not adhere to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a slight misconception on your side.

Timestamp is not a datatype. It was/is a synonym for rowversion, which is mentioned here:

> **! Note**
> The Transact-SQL rowversion data type is not a date or time data type. **timestamp is a deprecated synonym for rowversion**.

<sup>***Reference:** [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

When you are talking about time-stamping something, then you are actually talking about two things:

1. **Functions** that return some form of a date or date/time value.
2. Actual **data types** to store the returned values in a table.

The **rowversion** (timestamp; deprecated) was/is a propriety "feature" of SQL Server which contains a data type which was neither a data nor a time.

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. **The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.** To record a date or time, use a datetime2 data type.

<sup>***Reference:** [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

The referenced material might help you formulate your question slightly better or provide you with a reason to use **rowversion** or a combination of **date-time** functions with the appropriate **date-time** data types.

I've answered your question in a general way. However, answering your concrete questions is difficult, as they may be based on wrong assumptions/knowledge. Read through the referenced material and [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/283679/edit) your question if required.

Answer (score 2):

It is rowversion:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

It can be used for exmaple for data syncronizations between tables.
Please, take a look at this:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4545/synchronizing-sql-server-data-using-rowversion/

There are others methods for data syncronization but this is an option.